# How to Delete the ".pdf" from file names I've Pulled With OS Module

Tags: python, list, dataframe, pdf, sum

I've used the os module to pull file names and created a DataFrame from the titles like this:

```
   Invoice              Vendor       Amount
0     2131           FileName1    68.00.pdf
1     2132           FileName2    68.00.pdf
```

How can I delete the .pdf from the amounts so I can find the sum of that column?

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].str.rstrip('.pdf')
```

Comment: Just as a note [str.rstrip](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) takes a "set of characters to be removed". This command is removing any of the characters `.`, `p`, `d`, or `f` from the right side of strings. This likely _not_ the desired behaviour in most circumstances. _e.g._ the result of `pd.Series(['a.pdf', 'j.xlf', 'cap', 'q.d.f.p']).str.rstrip('.pdf')` is 'a', 'j.xl', 'ca', 'q'.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Amount']=df['Amount'].str.replace('.pdf','',regex=True)
df
```

```
Invoice     Vendor  Amount
0   2131    FileName1   68.00
1   2132    FileName2   68.00
```